# Extract files but not that ones that has a `DelCustsExports`

Tags: c#

I have these files names:

```
Erb3PCustsExport-303_20080318_223505_000.xml
Erb3PCustsExport-303_20080319_063109_000_Empty.xml
Erb3PDelCustsExport-303_20080319_062410_000.xml
```

I don't want to extract the files that ends with `empty`. I just want to extract the files that has `CustxExport` in its name, but if the file name has `DelCustsExport` I don't want to extract it.

#### What I have tried

This is my code

```
foreach (string file in Directory.EnumerateFiles(xmlFolder, "*CustsExport*.xml")
    .Where(fn => !Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(fn).EndsWith("Empty")))
```

#### The problem

That works to extract all the files that has `CustsExport` in its name, and not extracting the files that ends with `Empty`, but that doesn't work with files like `DelCustsExport`

Could you help please

Comment: Would a regular expression be OK?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could you not just add an additional condition in your where clause to make sure the file name doesn't contain `DelCustsExport`?

```
foreach (string file in Directory.EnumerateFiles(xmlFolder, "*CustsExport*.xml")
    .Where(fn => !Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(fn).EndsWith("Empty")
                 && !Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(fn).Contains("DelCustsExport")))
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know the exact rules you want, but regular expressions gives you a lot of freedom and flexibility. Just deducting what information I can from your example, this code should produce the desired results:

```
var validFilename = new Regex(@"(?<!Del)CustsExport.*(?<!Empty)\.xml$");
foreach (var file in Directory
    .EnumerateFiles(xmlFolder)
    .Where(fn => validFilename.IsMatch(fn)))
```